# How to install a WD Advanced Format Drive in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drive, format

I am doing a fresh install with a WD10EZEX hard drive and would like to know the steps necessary to align the hard drive correctly and get optimal performance.

Answer (score 1):

No steps required; default partition alignment is to an even MiB boundary, which is more than sufficient for 4kb drives.